# How can i recursively search for the amount of open space in a house layout?

Tags: java, recursion

I am taking grade 12 compsci and I am stuck on a problem regarding recursion. The context of this problem asks me to find the number of open spaces in a room given a starting row and column.

The 'X' represents the walls and the 'O' represents open space. Open space only counts if they are adjacent to each other, not diagonally.

Given this room layout, myHouse.roomSize(1,1) will return 21 and myHouse.roomSize(5,9) will return 5. if the starting row or column is a wall, it will return 0.

```
 012345678901234567
0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1XOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOX
2XXXXOOOXOOOOOOOOOX
3XOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOX
4XOOXXXXOXXXOOOOOOX
5XOOOOXXOOOOXXXOOXX
6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If anyone could give me some tips on how to solve this problem with recursion

I will be extremely grateful, thanks.

Edit: Here is my attempt at solving it so far, 
Edit2 (formatted now): changed maze to layout

```
public int roomSize (int row, int col)
{
    if (layout[row][col] == 'X'|| layout [row][col]== '*')
        return 0;
    if (layout[row][col] == 'O')
    {
    layout[row][col]='*';
    return 1 + roomSize(row + 1, col);
    return 1 + roomSize(row, col + 1);
    return 1 + roomSize(row - 1, col);
    return 1 + roomSize(row, col - 1);
    layout[row][col]='O';
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that the site requires is that questions include detail about what you've attempted so far.

Comment: This is a pretty intense problem for a 12th grade CS class.

Comment: `return` exits your current function; add a `total` variable and add to that with `+= 1 + roomSize(...`. Then, at the end, `return total;`. The reason for this is because your code will exit at the first return statement.

Comment: So is this **must** be done using recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode to help don't want to do your work for you

```
int roomSize(int row, int col)
|   bool [x][y] v; //Array to stored visited values x is the width of the maze y is the height
|     set all bools in v to false
|    return doRoomSize(row,col, v) 
end

int doRoomSize(int r, int c, v)
|    if( v[r][c] = true ||  layout [r][c]='X' )
|     | return 0
|    end-if
|    //Now we know that its a good value
|    
|This is a maze type problem so what you need to do is


int roomSize(int row, int col)
|   bool [x][y] v; //Array to stored visited values x is the width of the maze y is the height
|     set all bools in v to false
|    return doRoomSize(row,col, v) 
end

int doRoomSize(int r, int c, v)
|    if( v[r][c] = true ||  layout [r][c]='X' )
|     | return 0
|    end-if
|    //Now we know that its a good value
|    v[r][c] = true; // we have seen this point so we addit to visted
|      int n=1;
|    //Check left
|         n+= doRoomSize(r-1, c)
|    //Check right
|        n+=doRoomSize(r+1,c)
|   //Check up 
|        n+=doRoomSize(r,c-1)
|  // Check down
|        n+=doRoomSize(r,c+1)
|     return n;
end-method
```

Comment: His problem did not appear to be misunderstanding the algorithm. Note his use of `maze` instead of `layout` indicating he already implemented a searched array. Instead, it appears to be a coding error.

Comment: I do not really understand why you made a boolean array. What I did was modify the original array to change it to '*' is that also alright?

Comment: If your allowed to be destructive with your code( change the values of the arrays ) then you don't need the Boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement exits the function instantly; it assumes it has found the result and that no further calculations are necessary. Your function would exit after `return 1 + roomSize(row + 1, col);`, assuming that it had found the result. Instead, I recommend that you use a `sum` or `total` variable which you return after the rest of the function executes.

Try this:

```
public int roomSize (int row, int col) {
    if (layout[row][col] == 'X'|| layout [row][col]== '*')
        return 0;
    if (layout[row][col] == 'O') {
        int total = 1;

        maze[row][col]='*';
        total += roomSize(row + 1, col);
        total += roomSize(row, col + 1);
        total += roomSize(row - 1, col);
        total += roomSize(row, col - 1);
        maze[row][col]='O';
    }
}
```

EDIT: you change the value of `maze` to `*`, but when you check for `*` in the line `...layout[row][col] == '*')`, you are not checking `maze`.